# Spark: Does the data in RDD have the order?

Tags: apache-spark

I have a data set which has three labels for each data point.
For example:

```
7 0 0 0:0.588785046729 1:1 2:1 3:1 4:1 5:1 6:1 7:1 8:1 9:1 10:1 11:1 12:1 13:1 14:1 15:1 16:1 17:1 18:1 19:1 20:1 21:1 22:1
```

This is one data point with three labels using libsvm format. But it can't be read by MLLib so I transformed it into three points like:

```
7 0:0.588785046729 1:1 2:1 3:1 4:1 5:1 6:1 7:1 8:1 9:1 10:1 11:1 12:1 13:1 14:1 15:1 16:1 17:1 18:1 19:1 20:1 21:1 22:1 <br>
0 0:0.588785046729 1:1 2:1 3:1 4:1 5:1 6:1 7:1 8:1 9:1 10:1 11:1 12:1 13:1 14:1 15:1 16:1 17:1 18:1 19:1 20:1 21:1 22:1 <br>
0 0:0.588785046729 1:1 2:1 3:1 4:1 5:1 6:1 7:1 8:1 9:1 10:1 11:1 12:1 13:1 14:1 15:1 16:1 17:1 18:1 19:1 20:1 21:1 22:1
```

Now there is a task I must process the three kinds of data points simultaneously with the same order all the time. So I loaded the three kinds of data points to three RDDs. And after a full batch all the order should be shuffled just like the normal mini-batch learning. Is this possible? Does the data in RDD have the order? Or I should just create a new data structure and don't use the `LabeledPoint`.

Comment: Yes, RDDs are ordered, but depending on a transformation you use there is no guarantee that the original order will be preserved. Moreover full data shuffle can be prohibitively expensive.

Comment: So if in this case I have three labels which need to be trained simultaneously, does it have a optimal strategy? I loaded the data three times to three RDDs.

Comment: If you work on custom algorithm you can add a common identifier, use it for partitioning and select data for each batch by partition. I guess it is not the optimal solution though.

Comment: @zero323 saying that the data in RDDs is ordered is very misleading, there is an implicit order within each partition, however this will not be preserved between shuffles and between partitions. Could these data points not be grouped into a Vector and used simultaneously like that?

Comment: @JemTucker It could be misleading but it doesn't change the fact that RDDs are ordered. When you call `sortBy` there is no special magic involved. All get you get is `ShuffledRDD` followed by `MapPartitionsRDD`. All of that depends solely on a defined ordered of partitions and values per partition.